# How do I stop tracing a function in clisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, trace

I've been tracing a function `example`  with this call

```
(trace example)
```

and now I wish to stop tracing it, 
how can I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In common lisp it's as easy as calling [untrace](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_tracec.htm):

```
(untrace example)
```

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking stop-trace or something. Didn't think og the un- construction.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [untrace](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_tracec.htm).